# Automated time series forecasting with data from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, time-series

I am working on a project that includes creating a live online dashboard (Using bootstrap, visual studio and C# etc..) with a feature of having a time series forecasting.

The data source are from SQL Server. What is the best general approach to achieve this:

- Do I need to do the forecasting in the database exactly then just extract the results and show it to the dashboard OR.
- Do I need to extract the necessary data then do the forecasting in the visual studio and C# part.
- Or Am I missing something?.

Comment: Your question is still very broad. What data do you have to process/display? Images? Integers? Do you use a framework to visualize your data and in what format does it have to be delivered if so? Please try to add details to your situation with the help of [How to ask a Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Typically you'd take local copies of your data from source and load them into a BI-engine/database - let's say this:

```
Sales|Month
$100:Jan
$200:Feb
$300:Mar
```

At that point you'd perform your forecasting/markup/black magic - writing the data back into the BI database - this time marking up the 'real' and 'evaluated' records and doing any required aggregation.

Maybe your table would now look like this:

```
Sales|Month|Source
$100:Jan|SalesSystem
$200:Feb|SalesSystem
$300:Mar|SalesSystem
$400:Apr|ForecastingAlgorithm1234
$500:May|ForecastingAlgorithm1234
```

This combined source of reality/projection is then the proximate source for any visualisations or further analysis you need to run or present.

In this example the 'forecasting algorithm' is system agnostic - it can be performed in Visual Studio (.net etc) or in SQL Server depending on the technology you need.

The key here is to commit to a few simple principles:
- Maintain Data Lineage
- Don't write or 'work' in your source systems (use a separate BI SQL instance - or at least a DB)
- Maintain clarity over canonical and constructed data
- Don't do 'work' in memory - materialise it all into tables/DB for subsequent analysis and debugging - trust me - it WILL be wrong the first few iterations and its much easier to unpick materialised data than temporary!

Comment: You mean I need to have another Database aside from my data source db where I will put my extracted local copies of data? After that, how can I apply my forecasting algorithm to have results.

Comment: You don't have to - but it's absolutely good practice to keep 'real' and 'calculated' data logically distinct. I'm not sure what you mean by 'how can I apply my forecasting algorithm' I mean - there are literally infinite ways of doing that. Without sample data or a statement of intention that's just super broad.....

Comment: Can you give me atleast one way of doing that in this particular scenario. Where I will have an online dashboard that is connected to the SQL Server where my data will come from. Then from one click I can do forecasting to a specific "data". Sorry for being ignorant, I really dont know where to start. Thanks for the help anyways...

Comment: I mean can I do that in the SQL Server?